# ¿Por qué me imprime como resultado "Blanco\n Blanco"?

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de hacer un código que me permita hacer que se imprima un caracter y que a consecuencia de éste se le asigne un valor a otro, en este caso, "negro" o "blanco" pero por alguna razón me regresa "blanco" siempre ¿Qué hago mal?
Código:

```
struct colors{
char *x;
char *y;
char *z;
char *res;
}colors;

int main ()
{
    printf("Programa que imprime el color de los cuadros: \n");
    printf("Indique con qué color desea iniciar(negro o blanco): \n");
    scanf("%s", colors.x);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    printf("Indique qué color desea a la izquierda(negro o blanco): \n");
    scanf("%s", colors.y);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    printf("Indique qué color desea a la derecha(negro o blanco): \n");
    scanf("%s", colors.z);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    printf("Presione ENTER para iniciar\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();`
    printf("La tabla queda:\n");
    
    if (colors.z !="negro")
    {
        colors.res= "Blanco\n";
        printf("%s",colors.res);    
    }
    else
        colors.res= "Negro\n";
        printf("%s",colors.res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto es c, por lo que esto no sirve `colors.z!="negro"` porque solo estas comparando direcciones de memoria: 0xFab7==0x8978. Por lo que siempre te daria false(si es que el compilador lo permite), en vez de eso usa `strcmp(const char* str_1,const char* str_2);` que retorna true si str_1 es igual a str_2. Para usarla necesitas incluir `#include <string.h>`(pero también puedes hacer una función strcpy, solo tienes que recorrer la cadena y comparar char==char('a'=='b')) y recomiendo no usar `getchar()` dos veces,  por ultimo el else solo cubre `colors.res="negro";` por lo que recomiendo que hagas como con el if: `if (true){}else{}`.

Tambien haces esto:

```
char* input;
scanf("%s",input);
```

Lo que haces es acceder a memoria que no te pertenece(Nota: Cuando se usa una variable sin asignarle un valor(ya sea en tiempo de compilación o tiempo de ejecución), esta tendrá un valor muy inesperado(codigo de muestra: `int a;printf("El valor de a es %d\n",a);`). Lo mismo pasa con los punteros. Un puntero sin inicializar(tiempo de compilación y ejecución) puede apuntar a un lugar en la memoria que no te pertenece o incluso puede apuntar a tu mismo programa(Nunca se sabe a donde apuntará un puntero sin inicializar...)), la solución puede ya sea usar `malloc` o `crear` un array de x tamaño, para no complicar mucho la respuesta voy a crear un array de 25 char.

```
struct colors{
    char x[25];
    char y[25];
    char z[25];
    char res[25];
}colors;
```

si haces esta solución debes cambiar `colors.res="Negro"` o `"blanco"` por `sprintf(color.res,"Negro");//O blanco`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct colors{
    char x[25];
    char y[25];
    char z[25];
    char res[25];
}colors;//Le decimos al compilador que asigna memoria para 100 chars para usarlo en nuestro programa(recuerda hay mas manera de hacer este programa, pero solo enseño la que es mas sencilla desde mi punto de vista)

int main ()
{
    printf("Programa que imprime el color de los cuadros: \n");
    printf("Indique con qué color desea iniciar(negro o blanco): \n");
    scanf("%s", colors.x);
    getchar();
    printf("Indique qué color desea a la izquierda(negro o blanco): \n");
    scanf("%s", colors.y);
    getchar();
    printf("Indique qué color desea a la derecha(negro o blanco): \n");
    scanf("%s", colors.z);
    getchar();
    printf("Presione ENTER para iniciar\n");
    getchar();
    printf("La tabla queda:\n");

    if ( strcmp(colors.z,"negro")){
        //sprinft(colors.res,"Blanco");//No creo que necesites esta linea
        //printf("%s",colors.res);
        printf("Blanco");
    }else{
        //sprinft(colors.res,"Negro");//No creo que necesites esta linea
        //printf("%s",colors.res);
        printf("Negro");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me da una violación al segmento (`core' generado)

Comment: @Emma ya veo. Je si soy muy descuidado, : ) debes hacinarle memoria dinamica a los punteros para poder usarlo o crear un array de char. Ahora lo arreglo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Comment: @Emma Listo, ya lo solucione. Me equivoque también de funciones. strcpy es para copiar una cadena de str2 y lo guarda en str1, pero para la comparación se usa strcmp para comparar cadenas.